# How to get only integer value Started from Symbol from given string

Tags: php, regex

I need a integer value which started from £ and Â£ , I try to do with regrex but I only getting value which starting from Â£.

Here I use the regrex Like this.

```
if(preg_match('/(\£[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/',$vals,$matches))
{
$main[]= str_replace('£','',$matches[0]);
}
```

I am not familiar with regrex. so please share any solution. any help would highly appriciated.Thank you.

Comment: So you try to extract the integer from symbols like: £123 or Â£231 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I understand that you are having troubles with character encodings, so first of all I would suggest you to address this issue one step before, it is **really** important to resolve encoding issues in the earliest possible step.

Back to the question, first off, to avoid falling deeper into the charset encoding hell, I would recommend you to write your regexp literal in HEX, because otherwise **the charset encoding in which you save your PHP files would affect the result**. I.E. if you do something like this:

```
preg_match('/(£|Â£)(\d+)', ...)
```

It would match "£" and "Â£" (binary) **if** you save your source code in ISO-8859-1, **but** it would actually match "Â£" and "Ã‚Â£" (binary) if you chose to save your source code in UTF-8 (which might be a good idea in general). So be careful with this, and verify what your editor/IDE is doing!

My suggestion thus is to write it this way, which is equivalent for ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8:

```
preg_match('/(\xa3|\xc2\xa3)(\d+)', ...)     // match "£" and "Â£"
```

Also I suggest to make use of the sub-pattern capture feature of regular expressions, so you don't have to str_replace() afterwards, this way:

```
if (preg_match('/(?:\xa3|\xc2\xa3)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{2})?)/', $data, $regp)) {
  $main[] = $regp[1];
}
```

The "?:" at after the "(" means "this is a sub-pattern, but don't capture it".

Note that you can also replace preg_match with preg_match_all and you will find in $regp[1] the array of all matching numbers already prepared.

Comment: Thanks johnny Its really very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this modified regex:

```
(?:£|Â£)([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)
```

It should do the trick. But it will return you decimal values also, because of the:
    (.[0-9]{2})?

You can remove it and it will return only the integer part after £|Â£